# How to add a background behind a video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

how can you add a background image with a video in Blender?
 I would like to use a video from the screen of my phone (the size is in "portrait" mode), and add a background to fill the rest of the screen, so that it can fit the size in youtube.
Thanks

Edit: here is a good video that explains how to proceed (videos 11 and 12) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_dy4yMSJSw&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need is to add some strip at the bottom of the sequencer.

To add a solid color add a Effect Strip->Color and place it under your video strip.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how you set up the windows? Is it "movie editor" at the top and video editor at the bottom? Also how would you add an image, instead of a color?

Comment: Just use the **video editing** screen layout http://i.stack.imgur.com/WGuLo.png. To add an image as a strip use (spacebar+A) Add->Image

Comment: Thanks, ok I start to experiment it. Would you know how to have the image and the video at the same time in the same frame? I have got the "Cross" blend mode but it is either the video or the image. Or, is there a way to change the frame of the video, or the image?

Comment: Thanks, so here I found the rest of my question (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_dy4yMSJSw&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=12), thanks for the help.

Comment: For me, putting the `Color` Strip Above the Video and choosing the `Blend` mode of `Alpha Under` worked.

Comment: The problem is this breaks the "Remove Gaps" function because there are now never any gaps.

Comment: This is now more direct as you just go to `Add -> Color` rather than `Add -> Effect strip... -> Color`.